# Avoid showing LineNbr totals in Acumatica Report

Tags: c#, report, acumatica

I'm trying to avoid printing some SO Lines in the Sales order Report of Acumatica (SO641010) to do that I've added a Usr field to the SOLine DAC and DB Table by doing that I was able to stop showing the desired lines by adding the VisibleExpr as =[SOLine.UsrNoPrint] <> True but the totals at the bottom keep summarizing that line to the totals of the report.

Is there a quick way to prevent the addition of that line to the totals of the bottom of the report?

Comment: By default the totals on the Sales Order report are the Totals from SOOrder. Did you change that to use variables on the data from SOLine?

Comment: @Casval no, that should be the problem. Do you know how to change those total fields to work with the Usr modification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the same condition in the LineNbr variable in the 'Variables' dialog of the Details section. It will increments the LineNbr field on the same condition you use to show the records.

1. Click on the 'detailSection1' header to select it, or select it from
   the properties combo box.
2. Click on the ellipsis […] button right of 'Variables' in the properties tree view
3. Change LineNbr formula from `=$LineNbr+1` to

   `=IIf([SOLine.UsrNoPrint] <> True, $LineNbr+1, $LineNbr)`

[image]

Comment: I've tried it and it's still not working. I think it has to do with the comment of Casval... Because I haven't change the total fields to use variables on the data from SOLine. Do you know how to change those fields to work with the Usr modification?

Comment: LineNbr is the only Total variable in the report, check the first column of the detail section, it will display the LineNbr properly with that change. The footer fields are not report total variable and have nothing to do with LineNbr or report conditions, they're simple DB fields like SOOrder.CuryOrderTotal. These are the fields displayed in sales order top right form header. If you need dynamic total you need to create your own report variables just like $LineNbr and display that instead. To increment them $CustomTotal+[SOLine.field] instead of +1

Comment: Adding variable to reports is covered in T100 training material: https://openuni.acumatica.com/courses/development/t100-introduction-to-acumatica-framework/

Comment: I've tried it with a variable with the name CustomTotal and the ValueExpr =$CustomTotal+[SOLine.CuryLineAmt] and it's still summarizing the value of the UsrNoPrint lines

Comment: Did you put the condition in there too? ValueExpr =IIf([SOLine.UsrNoPrint] <> True, $CustomTotal+[SOLine.CuryLineAmt], $CustomTotal)

Comment: I've made it work by adding the following properties to the variable 
Name CustomTotal
ResetGroup groupInvoice
ValueExpr =$CustTotal+IIf( [SOLine.UsrNoPrint] <> True, [SOLine.CuryLineAmt], 0 )